# Reversal form of endosymbiotic theory?

Tags: evolution, cell-biology, microbiology

Cell's organelles give us [evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbiogenesis) that they might have been independent organisms on their own.

Are there any single-cell microorganisms known to have gone so to say this way back as well, i.e. having some evidence to have their past as part of a larger organism?

Comment: In the life-cycle of myxobacteria, there are uni- and multi-cellular stages.

Comment: It's not exactly what I've asked.. Slime molds same do not qualify. Still, good to know.

Comment: An organelle who did not come from an endosymbiosis does not contain DNA. It cannot just go away and leave on its own without hereditary material. A piece of DNA can however eventually leave a genome and become its own thing!

Answer (score 1):

Endosymbiosis leads to an irreversible loss of independence of the endosymbiont and the host.

For example, all members of the insect superfamily *Aphidoidea* (aphids) have an obligatory association with bacteria, commonly called primary endosymbionts (Munson et al., 1991; emphasis mine):

> The primary endosymbionts are found in **specialized** organs, the
> mycetomes, which consist of cells (mycetocytes) containing the
> endosymbionts. The endosymbionts are enclosed within vesicles which
> are derived from the cell membranes of the mycetocytes.
>
> None of the [primary] endosymbionts has been successfully cultivated in
> bacteriological media or in tissue culture. [These] organisms are **essential**
> for the life of the aphids since the removal of the endosymbionts by
> antibiotics leads to aphid sterility.
>
> The endosymbionts are  maternally **transmitted,** and
> there are complex mechanisms which assure that the progeny are
> infected.

Munson et al. (1991) *Buchnera* gen. nov. and *Buchnera aphidicola* sp. nov., a taxon consisting of the mycetocyte-associated, primary endosymbionts of aphids. Int J Syst Bacteriol 41: [566--568](http://ijs.microbiologyresearch.org/content/journal/ijsem/10.1099/00207713-41-4-566).

Comment: At SE we're looking for answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Otherwise how can the poster or anyone else know whether or not you are correct? See the Help for ["how do I write a good answer?"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).